# Sort by a value in a many to one field with a django queryset?

Tags: python, sql, django

I have a data model like this:

```
class Post(models.Model)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Tag(models.Model)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    rating = models.FloatField(max_length=255)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name="tags")
```

I want to get Posts that have a tag, and order them by the tags rating.

something like:
  Posts.objects.filter(tags__name="exampletag").order_by("tags(name=exampletag)__rating")

Currently, I am thinking it makes sense to do something like

```
tags = Tags.objects.filter(name="sometagname").order_by("rating")[0:10]
posts = [t.parent for t in tags]
```

But I like to know if there is a better way, preferably querying Post, and getting me back a queryset.

---

### Edit:

I don't think this: (**Edit 2 - this *does* give the correct sorting!**)

```
Posts.objects.filter(tags__name="exampletag").order_by("tags__rating")
```

will give the correct sorting, as it does not sort only by the related item with name "exampletag"
Something like the following would be needed

```
Posts.objects.filter(tags__name="exampletag").order_by("tags(name=exampletag)__rating")
```

I've been looking over the django docs, and it seem "annotate" *nearly* works - but I don't see a way to use it to select a tag by name.

---

### Edit 2

Both the Answers are correct! See my comments to observe some epic brain-farts (one test, the results WERE in order, the other i filter and sort by different tags!)

#### how it works

the query

```
Posts.objects.filter(tags__name="exampletag").order_by("tags__rating")
```

and

```
Posts.objects.filter(tags__name="exampletag").filter(tags__name="someothertag").order_by("tags__rating")
```

will work correctly and by sorted by the rating of "exampletag"

it seems the tag(From a ForeignKey BackReference Set) used for sorting when calling order_by is the one in the *first* filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even shorter than Anush's, with a JOIN rather than a subquery:

```
Post.objects.filter(tags__name='exampletag').order_by('tags__rating')
```

Comment: This seems to fail for the same reason. order_by sorts the set by either the first or last tag in the related items

Comment: for x in Post.objects.filter(tag__name='completed').order_by("tag__liquid_value"): print x.tag_set.filter(name="completed").first().liquid_value
RETURNS
0.0225187901566
0.0841032050442
0.102840550155
0.113329430864
0.125149692311
0.176613102005
0.308703835431
0.444648609296
0.609231624471
0.738393934709

Comment: Wow - massive failure on my part here! Both this and the answer by Anush seem to work! upvoting both and marking this as correct.

Answer (score 2):

You can do like:

```
tags = Tags.objects.filter(name="sometagname")
posts =  Post.objects.filter(tags__in=tags).order_by('tags__rating')
```

Comment: When using order_by 'tags_rating' - I don't think it knows to orderby "sometagname"  
in my test below Tag has an automatic backrefrence, and liquid_value is used instead of rating

Comment: In [38]: tags = Tag.objects.filter(name="atestingtag")
 ---------- 
In [39]: posts = Post.objects.filter(tag__in=tags).order_by("tag__liquid_value")
  ----------  
In [40]: for p in posts: print p.tag_set.filter(name="completed").first().liquid_value
0.444648609296
0.609231624471
0.113329430864
0.176613102005
0.125149692311
0.0225187901566
0.738393934709
0.0841032050442
0.102840550155
0.308703835431

Comment: I thought the question was to get all the posts that belong to a particular tag and order the posts by their tag rating, which my answer does. 
But if you want highest rated tag for each post, that can be done like:
for p in posts: print p.tag_set.filter(name="completed").order_by('rating').first().rating

Comment: You are correct! Your original answer does indeed do what I need, and what you said. Having misapplied your solution, I've explained in the original question, and will upvote your answer when SO lets me!